# Error en mi archivo de configuración de rutas al intentar pasar el username de componente padre a componente hijo

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Cuando intento pasar el nombre de usuario de mi componente padre al componente hijo para mostrarlo en el Header (hijo), me aparece un error que no entiendo como solucionar.

No hay problema si trato de pasar los datos del hijo al padre. Sin embargo, debido a las necesidades del proyecto, tengo que pasar los datos de usuario de padre a hijo. Estoy recibiendo  este error en mi archivo routeConfig y no sé muy bien por qué:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es la parte del código del componente padre desde el cuál tomo la info de usuario que viene en la interface ILoggedInUserData y que contiene el username:

```js
import { ILoggedInUserData } from "store/slice/auth/authSlice.types";

interface DashboardProps {
    loggedInUserData: ILoggedInUserData;
}

const PaceLabsDashboard = ({ loggedInUserData }: DashboardProps): JSX.Element => {
    // const [loggedInUserData, setLoggedInUserData] = useState<ILoggedInUserData>();
    console.log(loggedInUserData.name);

    return (
        <Box>
            {/* Header */}
            <Box sx={{ width: "100%", height: "72px" }}>
                <DashboardHeader username={loggedInUserData.name} />
            </Box>

            <Grid container sx={{ display: "flex", height: "900px", width: "100%", textAlign: "center" }}>
                {/* Right content */}
                <Grid item sx={{ border: "2px solid black", width: "70%" }}>
                    <LeadershipProfile />
                </Grid>
```

Este sería el componente hijo que debería mostrar en pantalla el nombre del usuario:

```js
interface DashboardHeaderProps {
    username: string;
}

const DashboardHeader = ({ username }: DashboardHeaderProps): JSX.Element => {
    const classes = styles.dashboardHeaderStyles();

    return (
        <Box className={classes.container}>
            <Box>
                <Typography className={classes.welcomeText}>Hello {username}, welcome back!</Typography>
            </Box>

            <Box className={classes.logoutContainer}>
                <CustomIcon className={classes.userIcon} icon={icons.userMenu} />
                <Link className={classes.logoutText} onClick={() => logout()}>
                    Logout
                </Link>
            </Box>
        </Box>
    );
};

export default DashboardHeader;
```

Y estas las líneas del archivo de rutas que dispara el error:

```js
{
        path: "/my-dashboard",
        element: <PaceLabsDashboard />,
 }
```

Y aquí están declarados los types:

```js
export interface ILoggedInUserData {
    userId: number;
    name: string;
    username: string;
    lastLoggedInDate: number;
    groupId: number;
}
```